# How can I automate installation of a package to Linux and Windows Virtual Machines on VMware ESX4?

Tags: vmware-esx, installation, patch-management

I would like to create an application that will traverse a Virtual Infrastructure using the vSphere Web Services API (this part I have handled) and perform and unattended install of some given package on Linux and Windows machines (this latter part I can't figure out. It looks like you can not use the VMware Update Manager to install custom packages http://communities.vmware.com/thread/205652 ).

Is this possible? If so how can it be done? Credentials/permissions are not an issue as the person running this application should have total access to the infrastructure.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the [(older) VIX API](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vix-api/)

There is a C example given at that link showing how to execute a simple commands within a guest and return some data. There are VIX functions for logging into Guests, copying files between Guest and host and vice versa, initiating\clearing snapshots as well as executing commands. There are more but given just those capabilities you should be able to build a robust installation framework to do what you need.